# phonegap childbrowser - change onClick to tap?

Tags: onclick, cordova

Im using the childbrowser plugin with phonegap and jqtouch. 
I have this in a menu list to open webpages:

```
<a href="#" 
onClick="PhoneGap.exec('ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage','http:// 
mobile.twitter.com/company');" >
```

The problem is that the onClick opens the childbrowser as soon as I 
touch it, and since I have this in a menulist, I cant scroll the list 
up and down without the childbrowser opens. 
So how can I change the onClick so it act as a tap instead? 
What do I have to do? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's worked for me is to use jQuery's bind approach and bind a tap event to the element that you'd like to call the Childbrowser.  Here's some generic HTML and JavaScript that should give you a sense of what to do:

**HTML:**

`<p class="urlStyle">Your link</p>`

**JavaScript:**

```
$('p.urlStyle').bind('tap',function() {
     window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.yourlink.com");
});
```

Comment: Hi Steven, and thanks. I have now tryed this in many ways but I cant get it working. Nothing happens, I even put an alert just below to see that something happens, but not even that is working? When I click the link and look in the consol, noting happens there!?